# What does lambda x, (y, z): x | (z << y) plays a part in reduce()?

Tags: python, lambda

The code is as below:

```
reduce(lambda x, (y, z): x | (z << y),
       enumerate(map(lambda i: 0 if i < avg else 1, im.getdata())),
       0)
```

What makes me confused is the first argument of `reduce()`

```
lambda x, (y, z): x | (z << y)
```

I get the meaning of other two arguments:

```
enumerate(map(lambda i: 0 if i < avg else 1, im.getdata())),
       0
```

Besides, I know that the lambda expression (the first argument of `reduce()`) is to turn a sequence of bits （0 or 1） into a integer. It seems we should do one bitwise right shift at one time, but here is `y`, what's that?

PS: my question is not the lambda expression itself, but how it works with the sequence which

```
enumerate(map(lambda i: 0 if i < avg else 1, im.getdata()))
```

returns

Comment: It is saying `x XOR (z left-shifted y times)`

Comment: I know that, but how does it works with reduce()? @Cyber

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly your confusion is? It might be easier if you split it up into more steps, so you could see exactly what each part is doing.

Comment: my question is not the lambda expression itself, but how it works with reduce()? @Lutz Horn  your edit didn't get my meaning

Comment: What do you mean *how it works with `reduce`*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  plays a part in reduce()

Comment: That hasn't really clarified the question. Do you know what `reduce` does? What its arguments are? Please be precise about what you don't understand (e.g. by explaining clearly every part of it you *do* understand).

Comment: @Cyber `|` is logical `OR` not `XOR`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `y` is the index of the item.
- `z` is the current item from the iterable.
- `x` is the result so far(with initial value of 0).

`x, (y, z)` is taking the advantage of tuple argument unpacking([supported in Python 2 only](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)), you can also write it as:

```
x = 0
for y, ind_item in enumerate(map(lambda i: 0 if i < avg else 1, im.getdata()):
    x |= (z << y)
```

Tuple argument unpacking in action:

```
>>> def func(x, (y, z)):
    print x, y, z
...     
>>> func(0, (10, 20))
0 10 20
```

Note that this feature has been removed in Python 3 and PEP-3113 recommends doing something like this:

```
def func(x, y_z):
    y, z = y_z
    print x, y, z
...     
>>> func(0, (10, 20))
0 10 20
```

As `lambda`s don't allow assignment statements, you can use indexing to get the value of `y` and `z`:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x, y_z: x | (y_z[1] << y_z[0]),
       enumerate(map(lambda i: 0 if i < avg else 1, im.getdata())),
       0)
```

Comment: Is there more info about tuple argument unpacking ?

Answer (score 0):

The signature is [`functools.reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce). From the doc:

> Apply `function` of two arguments cumulatively to the items of `sequence`, from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.

This translates to:

- Apply `lambda x, (y, z): x | (z << y)`
- to the items of `enumerate(map(lambda i: 0 if i < avg else 1, im.getdata()))`
- from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.

Since your `lambda` is a function "of two arguments" that can be applied to the the items of the `enumerate`, everything looks fine.

**Edit**

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns a list of tuples:

```
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
```

Comment: yep, the lambda is a function "of two arguments", but how to initialize   the second arguments (y, z) ?

Comment: @simon_xia `enumerate` produces a series of two-tuples `(index, element)`, which are then unpacked to the names `(y, z)` in the `lambda`.

Answer (score 0):

The entire statement is just turning a data image into a series of bits and then packing those bits into a single int.

A better, and more readable way of doing this might be to do something like.

```
import array
import numpy

pixel_data = numpy.array(data)
truth_values = pixel_data >= avg
byte_values = numpy.packbits(numpy.array(truth_values, dtype=int))
bit_string = array.array('B', byte_values).tobytes()
bit_int = int.from_bytes(bit_string, byteorder='big')
```

Comment: `im.getdata()` in the question is *probably* refering to PIL -- http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

Answer (score 0):

A bit late,

But here is the same code without the use of nested functions and lambdas:

```
class Img:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def getdata(self):
        return self.data

def function1(i):
    if i < avg:
        print "function1(%i) == 0"%i
        return 0
    else:
        print "function1(%i) == 1" % i
        return 1

def function2(y,z):
    print "function2(%i,%i) == %i"%(y,z,z << y)
    return z << y


avg = 0
im = Img(list(range(-5,5)))

MAP = map(function1,im.getdata())
print "\nMAP of function1 with im.getdata() == %s"%MAP
ENUM = list(enumerate(MAP))
print "\nENUM of MAP == %s\n"%ENUM
a = 0
for y, z in ENUM:
    print "a == %i"%a
    value = function2(y,z)
    print "a += %i"%(value)
    a += value

print "\nResult is\na == %i"%a
```

Output:

```
function1(-5) == 0
function1(-4) == 0
function1(-3) == 0
function1(-2) == 0
function1(-1) == 0
function1(0) == 1
function1(1) == 1
function1(2) == 1
function1(3) == 1
function1(4) == 1

MAP of function1 with im.getdata() == [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

ENUM of MAP == [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1)]

a == 0
function2(0,0) == 0
a += 0
a == 0
function2(1,0) == 0
a += 0
a == 0
function2(2,0) == 0
a += 0
a == 0
function2(3,0) == 0
a += 0
a == 0
function2(4,0) == 0
a += 0
a == 0
function2(5,1) == 32
a += 32
a == 32
function2(6,1) == 64
a += 64
a == 96
function2(7,1) == 128
a += 128
a == 224
function2(8,1) == 256
a += 256
a == 480
function2(9,1) == 512
a += 512

Result is
a == 992
```